# Paypal express create client with email/account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I have integrated `gem 'paypal-express'` in a rails app.

How can I pay to different accounts... 
customer need to pay for different accounts for different product. That a product has its own paypal account and during paypal transaction customer will go directly to the seller account and pay .

confusing with `Paypal::Express::Request.new PAYPAL_CONFIG`, It is basically set up for a static paypal account.

PAYPAL_CONFIG sets up new username, password, signature
But how can i go through the `email` of the account only?

is there anyway to achieve this without using this config ?

Thanks

Comment: You can use paypal config for using different paypal accounts why can to use it?

Comment: PAYPAL_CONFIG sets up new username, password, signature .This time product has only email of the paypal account and the customer need to connect that account and pay.But how can i go through the email of the account only?

Comment: I dont think it is possible with paypal express checkout.

Comment: @techvineet: ok, thanks.. is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: You need paypal signatures to communicate with paypal api anyways, without this it is not possible.